# jquery (this).parent.hasClass giving false positive while in animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use CSS animations and jQuery to open multiple flaps on a Calendar. That works great as long as the user waits for an animation to end and then clicks the next one. But the moment an opening animation is still running, and the user already starts the next, the script breaks and my class `opend` is removed from the `.fenster` div and window breaking the layout.

Does anybody see where my script is faulty?

```js
$( document ).on("click" , '.flap' , function(){
    if ($(this).parent(".fenster").hasClass("opend")) {
     $(this).removeClass("flap_open" ).addClass("flap_close" );
  $(this).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
      $(this).next().hide();
      $(this).removeClass("flap_close");
      $(this).parent(".fenster").removeClass("opend");
  });
 } else {
     $(this).addClass("flap_open" );
     $(this).parent(".fenster").addClass("opend");
     //$(this).removeClass("flap_close" );
     $(this).next().show();
 } 
});
```

```css
.fenster {
 width: 30%;
 min-width: 130px;
 max-width: 300px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(212, 212, 212, 1);
 position: relative;
    left: 200px;
 z-index: 200;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.opend {
 perspective: 1500px;
 -webkit-perspective: 1500px;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #2e2d2e;
 cursor: auto;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
  background-color: red;
}
.flap:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 75%;
}
.flap_open {
 transform-origin: 0 50%;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 100;
 cursor: alias;
 animation: turn 4s forwards;
 -webkit-animation: turn 4s forwards;
 box-shadow:  5px 0px 5px 0px #2e2d2e;
}
.flap_close {
 transform-origin: 0 50%;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
 -webkit-animation: zumachen 4s forwards;
 animation: zumachen 4s forwards;
 opacity: 0.8;
 box-shadow:  5px 0px 5px 0px #2e2d2e;
 transform: rotateY(-100deg);
}
.button{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 2%;
 left: 15%;
 width: 70%;
 height: 5vh;
 min-width: 80px;
 min-height: 28px;
 max-height: 20px;
 z-index: -1;
 text-align: center;
 display: table;
  background-color: grey;
}
@keyframes turn {
  to {
  transform: rotateY(-100deg); 
  opacity: 0.8;
  box-shadow:  5px 0px 5px 0px #2e2d2e;
  visibility: visible;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes turn {
  to {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-100deg); 
  -webkit-opacity: 0.8;
  box-shadow:  5px 0px 5px 0px #2e2d2e;
  visibility: visible;
  }
}
@keyframes zumachen {
  to {
  transform: rotateY(0deg); 
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow:  none;
  visibility: visible;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes zumachen {
  to {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  box-shadow:  none;
  visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fenster f7 p3">
<div class="flap"></div>
<div class="button" style="display: none;"><span>Something</span></div>
</div>
<div class="fenster f3 p1">
<div class="flap"></div>
<div class="button" style="display: none;"><span>Something</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a class indicating the animation is running, you can then run a check to make sure that any currently animating element will not be affected by the `.removeClass()` method called on any closing element.

1. Add a class to the animating element, indicating that it is in
   animation
2. With an additional `.one()` method to the `else` code block of your initial
   conditional statement you can remove this aforementioned class again
   once the animation has completed
3. Insert another conditional check in the first `.one()` method of
   your initial conditional check to verify that the element in
   question has no class `.animation-running`, therefore indicating
   that it should have the necessary classes removed.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".flap", function() {
  if ($(this).parent(".fenster").hasClass("opend")) {
    $(this).removeClass("flap_open").addClass("flap_close");
    $(this).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
      if (!$(this).parent(".fenster").hasClass("animation-running")) {
        /* only step into next code block if condition is equal to true, 
         * i.e: parent does not have the class "animation-running", so animation is completed 
         */
        $(this).next().hide();
        $(this).removeClass("flap_close");
        $(this).parent(".fenster").removeClass("opend");
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("flap_open");
    $(this).parent(".fenster").addClass("opend animation-running"); /* Additional class to indicate animation is running */
    $(this).next().show();
    /* Only once animation has completed should the indicating class be removed */
    $(this).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
      $(this).parent(".fenster").removeClass("animation-running");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.fenster {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 130px;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(212, 212, 212, 1);
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  z-index: 200;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.opend {
  perspective: 1500px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1500px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #2e2d2e;
  cursor: auto;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: red;
}

.flap:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 75%;
}

.flap_open {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: alias;
  animation: turn 4s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: turn 4s forwards;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px #2e2d2e;
}

.flap_close {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-animation: zumachen 4s forwards;
  animation: zumachen 4s forwards;
  opacity: 0.8;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px #2e2d2e;
  transform: rotateY(-100deg);
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 5vh;
  min-width: 80px;
  min-height: 28px;
  max-height: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  background-color: grey;
}

@keyframes turn {
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-100deg);
    opacity: 0.8;
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px #2e2d2e;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes turn {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-100deg);
    -webkit-opacity: 0.8;
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px #2e2d2e;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@keyframes zumachen {
  to {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: none;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes zumachen {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: none;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fenster f7 p3">
  <div class="flap"></div>
  <div class="button" style="display: none;"><span>Something</span></div>
</div>
<div class="fenster f3 p1">
  <div class="flap"></div>
  <div class="button" style="display: none;"><span>Something</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* its because you tell program - "on click, if this has class opend, do some, time-taking, work and remove opend class" Because you remove class at the end program doesn't go to that point if clicked again earlier. Way around could be to use other indicator top check the state. For ex:

```
$( document ).on("click" , '.flap' , function(){
        if ($(this).parent(".fenster").hasClass("justEmptyClass")) {
            $(this).parent(".fenster").removeClass("justEmptyClass");
```

Or use a variable - with false/rue to set and check state:

```
var open = true;
$( document ).on("click" , '.flap' , function(){
        if (open) {
            open = false;
```

// and rest your code

Comment: and also might need to reset styles to its primary state.